# Word or Phrase that means "a person who disregards their life while rescuing people in danger"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

Suppose a person saves the life of others without giving any thought that it could be dangerous, harmful, or life-threatening to himself. He doesn't care that this endeavour might harm, injure, or even kill him.

For example, if someone is trapped in a fire and another person saves, or tries to save the trapped person. Now to report this incident, I could frame a headline like this:

> A ___ person without caring his life, saved the lives of 3 people entrapped in fire.

"A brave person" is an obvious choice but I want to emphasize that he did so without even caring for his life.

What word(s), phrase, or idiom makes this clear?

Comment: Try *selfless*.

Comment: *Heroic* also contains at its core the idea of a willingness to sacrifice oneself for others.  BTW, "not caring *about* his own life..." or "with no thought for his own safety".

Comment: @TimRomano - Yep, "heroic" is the word alright - though it's been watered down by the drama-queen talking-heads on the evening news. I'll up-vote if you make it an answer.

Comment: I prefer "selfless". It has much less of the grandiose (and self-important?) about i.t

Comment: @DanBron you really must stop giving answers in comments. If you think the question is too basic, then vote to close it as off-topic. The time it takes to write the comment is the same for an answer, just add a definition and it's done.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I do think it's too basic, and could be answered by using a thesaurus, starting at OP's original *brave*. And no, it is not as easy to write an answer as it is to add a comment, especially from a phone. I'm telling you this from direct experience. None the less, in case you hadn't noticed, since our previous conversation on this topic, I have made a concerted effort to add more answers and fewer comment-answers. But I didn't think *this* question warranted that treatment. Last point: my broad offer still stands: any user is free to offer any of my comments in his own answer.

Comment: *Self-sacrificing* - my answer in a comment.

Comment: ...without caring **for** his life...  (which, by the way, becomes redundant once you add the right word in your blank.)

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock: I think you are right. If I drop the phrase "without caring for his life" from my headline, either of the words-"selfless, heroic or self-sacrificing" sounds right.

Comment: Slightly negative and perhaps mocking to most of us in the West: "martyr"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hero you describe is **self-sacrificing**

http://i.word.com/idictionary/self-sacrifice

Comment: I do not think that word is appropriate here. From your reference, the meaning is "the act of giving up something that you want to have or keep in order to help someone else", so with that meaning, unless that hero died (or lost something) in his act of saving others, it would not fit much. Eg "A self-sacrificing person without caring his life, saved the lives of 3 people entrapped in fire, and later died due to severe burns." (((( Meanwhile, somebody came along and downvoted all other "more appropriate" answers, but I will not do the same ))))

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is part of **an altruistic character**.  Such person may at times risk his own life to save someone in danger.  Of course other personality traits can lead someone to do that and most of the adjectives already mentioned can also be used.

> - altruism (noun) - "unselfish concern for the welfare of others, behavior by an animal that may be to its disadvantage but that benefits others of its kind." - [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/altruism)
> - altruist (noun), altruistic (ajd), altruistically (adv)

Answer (score 0):

Few possibilities, from the synonyms of **Brave** which involve Danger/Fear/Risk in the meaning :

**Daring** : Willing to undertake things that involve risk & danger

**Spirited** : Willing to face danger

**Dauntless** : Invulnerable to fear & intimidation

**Intrepid** : Invulnerable to fear & intimidation

**Plucky** : Marked by courage & determination in the face of difficulties & danger